# How to 301 redirect an entire domain while preserving the path

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I am redirecting one domain to another, but I want to preserve the path in the redirect. So for example, I want to visit `www.example.com/services/education/page.html`, but my redirect will bring them to `www.new-example.com/services/education/page.html`. What do I write in my .htaccess file to preserve the path "/services/education/page.html"?

Right now I have:

```
redirect 301 http://www.example.com/ http://www.new-example.com/
```

But I'm not sure if that works or not (Can't test yet as I am waiting for domain details etc). I just want to be sure when I put the site live. Is that right or am I way off base?

Thanks!

Comment: You can still test before you get your domain details with an existing domain e.g. google.com or even non-existent as all you want to see is that the 301 redirect is issued in all cases that you want it while preserving your path.

Comment: Helicon has a RegexTest app which allows you to test .htaccess entries.  It'll even generate a rule for you, based-on your input/tests.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

This should do it:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !new-example.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://new-example.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Comment: My .htaccess file already has this code (Wordpress) in it: <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule> do I need those 4 lines of code you gave me? Or will I have a problem putting in RewriteEngine On twice (same for RewriteBase /)

Comment: skip the first two lines if they already exist in your .htaccess

Comment: These redirects are not working. The only code I have in my .htaccess is posted in my comment above. Is there a reason its not working?

Comment: I even took out all the code in my .htaccess file and just put your code in and it still doesn't work.

Comment: note that than you change to your real domain name `new-example.com` both times, old one don't take part

Answer (score 13):

try adding the following to your .htaccess in the root of your example.com domain

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

#for all requests to www.example.com
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.example\.com$
#redirect them to new-example
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.new-example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: This worked great but I found that it fails to redirect when you enter example.com (without www) in the browser. I removed `www\.` from the code above and it solved this issue but then the redirect fails if you enter www.example.com in the browser. How can this be fixed for both cases?

Answer (score 8):

Your original command uses the [`mod_alias`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_alias.html#redirect) Apache module, and it would work, though you may want to update it to:

```
Redirect 301 / http://www.new-example.com/
```

Removing the exact domain of the current (old) domain means all domains that point to that folder will be sent to the new domain, making that one-line script more robust.

The other answers use the [`mod_rewrite`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html) Apache module. If you have that also installed, that's fine to use, though it's 4+ lines of code compared to one. Additionally, `mod_alias` is part of the "base" package, so should be on all Apache servers, while `mod_rewrite` is an optional extension, so some might not have it.

Comment: Works very well. This seems like the best of the answers due to not beeing dependent on mod_rewrite.

Comment: does this preserve the path?

Comment: @JulesColle yes it does