# 301 Redirects from old.com to new.com

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, seo, http-status-code-301

My aim is to redirect my current old domain to my new domain. All the page structures are the very same, only thing that has changed is the domain.

I'm wanting to redirect the entire site to the new domain within my .htaccess file. What exact line of code will I use?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to 301 redirect an entire domain while preserving the path](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8450573/how-to-301-redirect-an-entire-domain-while-preserving-the-path)

Comment: I saw some useful answers there. I have been seeing them all over the internet, which it doesn't make it any clearer, with a lot of different options. I have over 20,000 pages that need redirecting with a 301 and I'm trying to find an easy solution.

Comment: The accepted answer to that question does exactly what you're asking for.

Comment: Okay, I will give them a go. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Are you using `mod_alias` Apache module?

```
Redirect 301 / http://www.new-domain.com/
```

Use the mod_rewrite Apache module

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://new_domain.com/ [R=301]
```

Maybe:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^old_domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://new_domain.com [R=301,L]
```

This is a [good tutorial](http://www.inmotionhosting.com/support/website/redirects/setting-up-a-301-permanent-redirect-via-htaccess) about your problem...

Comment: Okay, I will give them a go. Thanks