# .htaccess redirect for https://.co.nz website to .com version(including all subpages)

Tags: .htaccess, web, migration, redirect

I am palling to migrate my website from the .co.nz to the .com but need to setup a 301 redirect so all of the individual pages will still be routed properly without any 404 pages from .co.nz version

All https://

I want "https://www.example.co.nz/" to go to "https://www.example.com"

Which will also redirect

https://www.example.co.nz/contact to go to https://www.example.com/contact
https://www.example.co.nz/men to go to https://www.example.com/men

Many Thanks

Comment: To ensure, you know what you are doing, you probably would want to read apache's documentation for redirecting via mod_rewrite: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/remapping.html

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I am not sure how do I migrate my old domain(.co.nz) to new domain(.com) version.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to 301 redirect an entire domain while preserving the path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8450573/how-to-301-redirect-an-entire-domain-while-preserving-the-path)

Comment: What about https version?

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick:

```
Redirect 301 / https://www.new-example.com/
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !new-example.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://new-example.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

You put this in the .htaccess file of the .co.nz domain. This will redirect all your content and subfolders to their appropriate subfolders on the new domain (so example.me/subfolder to example.com/subfolder) AND also force redirect to https part.

Comment: Thanks @Haris. Could you please explain the first line of the code? You have mentioned http:// not https://. But both of our website has https://. Also, I want to know that if I add this code will it also redirect other products pages? Do I need to crawl the whole website and then redirect each single link to the new website? Thanks

Comment: I have edited the first line, I entered http by mistake (it should be, of course, https). It will redirect everything after / to the appropriate site. So if you have example.co.nz/product/page/123 it will redirect it to example.com/product/page/123 - it is up to you if you have that product on the new .com domain. You will have to do some manual work, of course.

Comment: Thanks @Haris. Should I put this on .co.nz?

Comment: Yes, on the .co.nz site as you will be making a redirect from that site to the .com site.

Comment: After writing this code where can I add redirection for subpages?

Comment: Hi, I am redirecting the subpages first to the new website subpages as they are not same and I do not want all URLs to go to the homepage of new domain. So now old-domain/about-us redirects to new-domain/about-us?url/=about-us/           What's that?