# When typing my website's URL with a subfolder, why does the subfolder name get combined with the URL name?

Tags: apache, url, dns

For some reason, when I type in my website's short-form URL (without WWW), any subfolders get smushed into the end of the domain name, and I end up getting my ISP's error page.

[hudsons.network/weather](http://hudsons.network/weather) as an example

But entering my website's URL *with* WWW works just fine.

[www.hudsons.network/weather](http://www.hudsons.network/weather)

At the same time, just typing in hudsons.network redirects to [www.hudsons.network](http://www.hudsons.network), the way I had configured it in Apache.

Here's my configuration:

- I have two Virtual Hosts, one for hudsons.network (the default) and another for [www.hudsons.network](http://www.hudsons.network) (my own)
- In the configuration file for the default host, I have this line:
  `Redirect permanent / http://www.hudsons.network`

I've seen similar behavior on Safari, Opera, and Internet Explorer, and I think it has to do with my website's redirects. Why is this happening, and what rules do I need so that my site redirects the way I expect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8450573/how-to-301-redirect-an-entire-domain-while-preserving-the-path). I also deleted the RewriteBase line because my config file is in /etc/apache2/sites-available. Works like a charm!